highcharts disable legend interaction
ive seen a couple of solutions that disables the legend click but it does not appear to work - possibly because of highcharts version.  here is an example:
Disable-Click on Legend in HighCharts Column Graph
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37129
the jsfiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pawel_dalek/5a8qr9zb/
i do realize the post is old but the fiddle shows the issue.  the legend is still clickable even if you are capturing the legend click event.


$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
      name: 'Berlin',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
      name: 'London',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>




You're totally right. The solutions you mentioned don't work anymore because, as of version 11.4.4 of Highcharts, the events.legendItemClick function has been deprecated. You can see this in the changelog: https://www.highcharts.com/changelog/
Now to disable the click on the legend item you should use legend.events.itemClick function. API references: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.events.itemClick
Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t327qj08/
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  legend: {
    events: {
      itemClick: function() {
        return false;
       }
     }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 3]
  }]
});

